# Using PHP-IMAP to retrieve emails from host in Symfony 4 and Sonata-admin

Tags: php, symfony4, symfony-sonata

I am using this library https://github.com/secit-pl/imap-bundle with Symfony 4 to retrieve emails from the server , and I followed the instructions they put at the bottom of the page . I am trying to use Gmail as an example. But I am getting this error message

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Service "secit.imap" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\IndexController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Unless you need extra laziness, try using dependency injection instead. Otherwise, you need to declare it using "IndexController::getSubscribedServices()".").

the code that I am using to connect is

the **imap.yaml**

```
imap:
connections:
    example_connection:
        mailbox: "{localhost:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX"
        username: "email@example.com"
        password: "password"

    another_connection:
        mailbox: "{localhost:143}INBOX"
        username: "username"
        password: "password"
        attachments_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/imap/attachments"
        server_encoding: "UTF-8"
```

The **controller**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use SecIT\ImapBundle\Service\Imap;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class IndexController extends AbstractController
   {
public function indexAction(Imap $imap)
   {
       $exampleConnection = $imap->get('example_connection');
       $anotherConnection = $imap->get('another_connection');

   }
```

and testing it as follows

```
$exampleConnection = $imap->get('example_connection');

   $isConnectable = $this->get('secit.imap')-> 
   testConnection('example_connection');
    var_dump($isConnectable);
```

But apparently it does not find the service "secit.imap"

Comment: Have you added `SecIT\ImapBundle\ImapBundle::class` to `bundles.php`? Also, you're missing a `>` after `$this->get('secit.imap')-` (but I'm assuming it's correct in your actual code as you're getting that error).

Comment: the **SecIT\ImapBundle\ImapBundle::class** exists in **bundles.php** and I have corrected the missing >